# pyspark use my field with reserved by the system name

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, spark-structured-streaming

How can i use my column with name 'count' in agg query? The error tells about problem with type but i think problem that 'count' is reserved by the system/

```
json_schema = StructType([
    StructField("userId", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("count", IntegerType(), True),
    StructField("dt", TimestampType(), True),
])

 .select(from_json(col("value").cast("string"), json_schema).alias("data"))
 .select("data.*")
 .groupBy(window(col("dt"), "30 seconds"))
 .agg(      sum("count").alias("sum_salary"), \
            avg("count").alias("avg_salary"), \
            max("count").alias("max_bonus")) \
```

and got error:

```
  .agg(sum("count").alias("sum_salary"), \
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

**Update 1:**

Omg i found the problem.
I have import like:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import window, from_json, to_json, col, count, avg, struct, sum
```

And then i use `sum("count")` called sum from python even though I've been explicitly told which one to use.

How fix:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
f.sum("count").alias("sum_count"),
```

Comment: is there a pyspark dataframe missing before the first `.select`? also what happens if you change the name of the field from `count` to `count_test`?

Comment: added .select(col("userId"), col("dt"), col("count").alias("x"));  and change to sum("x")   - dont work too. same exception =( maybe problem with types but i use StructType and filed is IntegerType.  DF from kafka makes no sense

Comment: have you imported [pyspark's `sum` function](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.3.0/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.sum.html#pyspark-sql-functions-sum)? side note - as a best practice, you should not import functions as `*`. instead, you should import the function package (or individual functions) with an alias.